# Rename files from csv list, performing too many loops

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

Being a PowerShell beginner I have constructed this code that gets each pdf in a folder and renames according to names located in a csv.

The code below does work but it is looping too much resulting in multiple below error:

> cannot create a file when that file already exists

```
$folderpath = read-host -Prompt 'enter folder path'
$data = import-csv "C:\listofnames.csv"
foreach ($d in $data) {
    Get-ChildItem $folderpath -Filter *.pdf |  
    foreach-object { rename-item -path "$folderpath\$_" "$($d.firstname) $($d.lastname).pdf" } 
}
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Removing -process has no effect

Comment: You are trying to rename all the files the same. Inside your `foreach` you are trying to rename every .pdf to `"$($d.firstname) $($d.lastname).pdf"`. This will crap out as soon as you try to rename the second .pdf. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: With your advice looking at the code again. I can see that it's getting a list of  all pdf's within that folder for each line in the csv.

I'm trying to create a script to rename a bunch of generic scans from a photocopier to names provided by a csv list.

Example being:
1000.pdf = Student 1
1001.pdf = Student 2

Comment: How do you map a row in your .csv file to a .pdf? Is just the nth row gets paired with the nth .pdf? What happens if there are more .pdfs than rows?

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies in the way you used `Rename-Item`:

Note that you don't need to use `ForEach-Object` since Rename-Item already iterates through the input.

```
foreach ($d in $data) {
    Get-ChildItem $folderpath -Filter *.pdf | 
    Rename-Item -newname {"$($d.firstname) $($d.lastname).pdf" }
}
```

**Speculation time:**

I noticed your script probably only works if there is only one file to rename per folder. Notice that `Get-ChildItem` could potentially return more than one file, but both of those will be named `[firstname] [lastname].pdf`, which will return exactly your error. I recommend you review your code structure.

**EDIT**:

Effectively, after rereading my answer post-speculation, and seeing the other answer, I noticed my code will not help you avoid this structural issue. You'll have to clarify on what you want to do, exactly, if not **"rename all pdf files within this folder to exactly the same name"** (which is effectively impossible with more than one file).

Answer (score 0):

```
$folderpath = read-host -Prompt 'enter folder path'
$data = import-csv "C:\listofnames.csv"
foreach ($d in $data) { ***
```

> for every name in your file

---

```
    Get-ChildItem $folderpath -Filter *.pdf |  <---
```

> you are retreiving EVERY pdf

```
    foreach-object { rename-item -path "$folderpath\$_" "$($d.firstname) $($d.lastname).pdf" }
```

> and trying to rename EVERY PDF with the person's name.

You need to rethink this and figure out a way to either map a number to a name, or hope that your list of pdfs' count matches that of your count of names to accomplish anything.

This isn't going to be pretty but this will do what you are thinking (I would totally make a copy of all these files before running this...):

```
$pdfs = get-childitem $folderpath -Filter *.pdf
0..($data.count-1)|%{
rename-item -path $(split-path $pdf[$_].fullname -parent) -newname "$($data[$_].firstname) $($data[$_].lastname).pdf"
}
```